# IE 8 css comment question

Tags: css

Hello as always there are some differences with looks of websites in firefox and IE 8, now my problem is I have some paragraphs that are not properly aligned so I'd like to add some margin properties for them, the problem is that they are not found in the style sheet but in the head element of html within style tags ... how can I change this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming you mean the CSS is in the `head` element of your HTML instead of in your CSS file, what problem are you having removing the CSS in the `head` element and putting it in your stylesheet?

For example, instead of:

```
<head>
<style type="text/css">
hr {color:sienna}
p {margin-left:20px}
body {background-image:url("images/back40.gif")}
</style>
</head>
```

Put these three lines in your CSS:

```
hr {color:sienna}
p {margin-left:20px}
body {background-image:url("images/back40.gif")}
```

For more, see the W3School's [CSS How to](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/css_howto.asp).

If you can only change the stylesheet, then try using `!important` to override the styles defined in the `head` element:

```
p { margin-left: 50px !important; }
```

Comment: well I've just joined the project .. and I'm not really supposed to change things this early .. I need to just make it work

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try

```
 <!--[if gt IE 6]>
```

....
....
....

```
<![endif]-->
```

Change new style inside .. style

Answer (score 0):

You can move the css out of the header into a new css file named for that page (assuming this css is specific to this one page/section) then run conditional selection on the css sheet (which from your description I get the impression you have done already for others).

Your other option would be to figure out why the code is not working on both browsers and adjust it until it works.